# Return values in C

Tags: c, return-value

```
void draw( int I, long L );
long sq( int s );

int main()
{
    long y;
    int x;

    y = sq( x );
    draw( x, y );
    return();
}  

long sq( int s )
{
    return( s * s );
}

void draw( int I, long L )
{
    return;
}
```

What is the difference between `return()`, `return (S*S)` and `return`? Please give an explanation.

Comment: return is not a function. You can do without the ()parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

Well:

`return();` is illegal, have you tried compiling?

`return(s*s)` is the same as `return s*s;` and it tells the function what value to return.

For example, if you would have:

```
 long x = sq(1);
 //x would be 1 here
```

`return;` exits from a `void` function. You can't put an empty return statement inside a function with a non-void return type. Put at the end of a void function, it does nothing. But  you can use it to exit the function early:

```
void foo()
{
    if ( someCondition )
       return;
    statement1;
    statement2;
    return;
}
```

The first `return` has the effect that it will exit the function if `someCondition` is `true`. So the statements will not be executed. The second `return` makes no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

There is hardly any difference.

Basically there are two syntaxes.

First of all:

```
return somethinghere;
```

is exactly the same as

```
return (somethinghere);
```

You can replace "somethinghere" with anything you want (as long as it qualifies with the function's return type), an equation another funciton anything that has a value, including simply nothing if the return type is "void".

If you put nothing, then it means you function returns nothing, otherwise you are returning the result of whatever you have placed there.

Comment: @Kabir actually this is wrong. This isn't PHP or JavaScript; it's C, a strongly-typed programming language. You can't return anything you want. Your return type is restricted by the function declaration.

Comment: By anything I have meant any thing ranging from a Literal value, a variable a function call etc.

Comment: Next time, remember to tag the person you're replying to using '@'. I removed the downvote.